# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-cli, onesignal

I'm trying to initialize OneSignal to a PhoneGap application.

I tried many ways. But always it gives following error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined",
>   source: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js error.

This is my app.js file

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
oneSignal();
checkConnection();}

function oneSignal(){
console.log("It is calling");
    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    };

    window.plugins.OneSignal.init("my app id",
                             {googleProjectNumber: "my project number"},
                             notificationOpenedCallback);



 // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
    window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);}
```

Somebody please help me to initialize OneSignal to my PhoneGap application.

Comment: Onesignal, can you please post the plugin link? The source from where you got it? Also the purpose for the same.

Comment: [link](https://onesignal.com/) This plugin is for push notifications.

Comment: Did you install the plugin, and cross verified it exists in the plugin folder? The error usually comes in case the plugin was not installed successfully.

Comment: Yes I installed the plug-in. Thank you very much for your help. And now it is working. It was a duplication problem of config.xml file. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: There are three (3) different systems for Corodova/Phonegap [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001). You are using CLI. *Phonegap Build* is a cloud-based build system by Adobe/Phonegap. I have updated your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Just try installing your plugin, cross verify for it's availability in the `plugins` folder. Also confirm the corresponding update has been made in `config.xml` and `fetch.json` (in the plugins folder). The error usually arises in case the plugin is not installed properly.

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Error was the duplication of the phonegap-version

Comment: Can you explain more @Choxmi - I have this same error

Answer (score 1):

The best way to initialize OneSignal is by adding the code in your controller.js file and make sure its in one of your controllers - it might be login, logout, anything.

in other words you need to add the code inside a set controller that responds to a certain action.

Cant explain it better but try that -..

Good luck